# Find roots of a function a x^n + bx - c = 0 where n isn't an integer with Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, equation

I'm writing a program in python and in it I need to find the roots of a function that is:

```
a*x^n + b*x -c = 0
```

where `a` and `b` are constants that are calculated earlier in the program but there are several thousand of them.
I need to repeat this equation twice for all values of `a` and `b` once with `n = 77/27` and once with `n = 3`.

How can i do this in python?
I checked `numpy.roots(p)` and that would work for when `n = 3` I think. But for `n = 77/27` how would I be able to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your beast choice is [`scipy.optimize.brentq()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html):

```
def f(x, n, a, b, c):
    return a * x**n + b * x - c

print scipy.optimize.brentq(
    f, 0.0, 100.0, args=(77.0/27.0, 1.0, 1.0, 10.0))
```

prints

```
2.0672035922580592
```

Comment: I actually agree... this might be the best because i pick the range over which it gets the root but theres still the issue of deciding what that should be, same as the issue with deciding what the starting point should be using Newton's method

Comment: Im getting an error saying:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/saad/Documents/Testing.py", line 6, in <module>
    print scipy.optimize.brentq(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'optimize'

Comment: @sbeleidy: You need to `import scipy.optimize` first -- just `import scipy` isn't enough.

Answer (score 5):

Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) and [here](http://wj32.wordpress.com/2008/02/23/polynomial-roots-using-the-newton-method-python/).

I'm so proud of myself, I still remember the specifics (without reading the link!) :)

If you don't get that, look [here](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/mpmath/calculus/optimization.html).

Comment: I dont understand how the last function works.... and which part of this is the one that I would run? Im guessing its the one im not understanding... that would make the most sense... but i dont really understand the parameters

Comment: Okay, do you know any calculus?

Comment: Yes I do know calculus.... I think understand the math behind it I just dont understand how the function does it.I dont understand how i am supposed to decide on the start x1 for example and what exactly r_i is

Comment: Ok so ive run the code several times to see how it acts and its right most of the time but if i give it a far starting point it gives weird numbers... im guessing the r_i is if it has more than one root?

Comment: Im actually liking the first link much better now ive realised that r_i is actually whether or not i want it to return the number of iterations it took to get done.... My only issue is actually now a math issue and thats what starting point do i use? Ive been testing this and comparing to wolframalpha, sometimes its exactly the same answer and sometimes its way off...especially in the case where there is more than one root...any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, that's the difficult part. Use the intermediate value theorem to figure out where a root must exist. Or, just use the minimum value of the function if you know they don't go too far negative.

Comment: Whoever just upvoted my answer, I'm still here, and I still appreciate it :)

Answer (score 5):

I would use `fsolve` from scipy,

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def func(x,a,b,c,n):
    return a*x**n + b*x - c

a,b,c = 11.,23.,31.

n = 77./27.

guess = [4.0,]    

print fsolve(func,guess,args=(a,b,c,n)) # 0.94312258329
```

This of course gives you *a* root, not necessarily *all* roots.

---

**Edit: Use `brentq`, it's much faster**

```
from timeit import timeit

sp = """
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from scipy.optimize import brentq

from numpy.random import uniform
from numpy import zeros

m = 10**3

z = zeros((m,4))
z[:,:3] = uniform(1,50,size=(m,3))
z[:,3] = uniform(1,10,m)

def func(x,a,b,c,n):
    return a*x**n + b*x - c

"""

s = "[fsolve(func,1.0,args=tuple(i)) for i in z]"
t = "[brentq(func,0.,10.,args=tuple(i)) for i in z]"

runs = 10**2

print 'fsolve\t', timeit(s,sp,number=runs)
print 'brentq\t', timeit(t,sp,number=runs)
```

gives me,

```
fsolve  15.5562820435
brentq  3.84963393211
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a root finding algorithm like Newton's method.   All root finding algorithms will work with non-integer powers.  They need not even be rational numbers.